# How can I prevent proxying if index file exists NGINX?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, proxy

I have a NGINX server with proxy to apache.
Wp-Rocket making all cache job, and store cache files to wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/
Each index file saved as **index-https.html**
The idea is to prevent proxying if the index file already exists.
Each time I refresh the page, I see GET requests in Apache logs.
Can you please point me what I'm doing wrong?

```
root /var/www/html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    error_page 420 = @apache;
    return 420;
}

location / {
    index index.html index-https.html;

    error_page 420 = @apache;
    error_page 405 = @apache;

    if ($request_method = POST ) {
        return 420;
    }
    if ( $query_string ){
        return 420;
    }
    if ( $http_cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in" ){
        return 420;
    }
    expires 365d;

    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";

    gzip_static on;

    try_files $uri wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/$uri/ @apache;
}

location @apache {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
}
```

Tried to specify index files (index-https.html) but no luck
also tried:

```
try_files $uri wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/$uri/ @apache;
try_files $uri /wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/$uri/ @apache;
try_files $uri /wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/$uri @apache;
try_files $uri /wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/$uri/index-https.html @apache;
```

Comment: All of your `try_files` are wrong. What is the GET request to Nginx and the corresponding full path of the `index-https.html` file it should respond with. The actual GET line from the nginx access log is required together with the full path of the file from `/var`.

Comment: Oh. I thought this path starts from the server root which is `/var/www/html`

basically I need this path from NGINX log - `/resumes/marina-7/`
 And it should take html from `/var/www/html/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/resumes/marina-7/index-https.html` or event better to take  `/var/www/html/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/resumes/marina-7/index-https.html_gzip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI `/resumes/marina-7/` should point to the file `/var/www/html/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com/resumes/marina-7/index-https.html`

The value of `$uri` is exactly `/resumes/marina-7/`, so take care you do not insert extra `/`s before or after the variable.

Use:

```
try_files $uri /wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/mysite.com${uri}index-https.html @apache;
```

Notice that the term must begin with a `/` and that braces are used to delimit the variable name.